# ASP.NET Model Protection

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a new-ish developer on staff who is creating models with a sort of interface variable to "protect" other variables.  The code kinda looks like this:

```
public class stuff
{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
   public int thingType { get; set; }
}
public class people
{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public sting name { get; set; }
   private IEnumerable<stuff> ourThings;
   public IEnumerable<stuff> things { get {return ourThings; } }
}
```

I assumed that if I didn't want to risk someone modifying a model, I would make my set method for those variables private.  I'm also not aware of how this can influence\prevent an attack on my site.  Has anyone ever seen or heard of this before?  If so, can you explain what the purpose really is and what I am trying to protect?

Thanks again!

Comment: I'm assuming they are using IEnumerable<stuff> as a way to prevent someone from calling .Add(Stuff) directly on the collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the overall problem with this entire thing:

```
private IEnumerable<stuff> ourThings;
public IEnumerable<stuff> things { get {return ourThings; } }
```

is that the collection can still be modified. You don't need a `set` to modify a collection because it's a reference type. But, if you wanted to make it immutable by design you might do something like this:

```
private IEnumerable<stuff> ourThings;
public IEnumerable<stuff> things { get {return ourThings.ToList(); } }
```

because that will build a *copy* of the original collection. That's one way of doing it anyway, and it proves to be pretty successful.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

I still don't completely understand what this is trying to protect.  The application being written is pretty small.  I'm not worried about another developer accidentally adding modifying and saving a model they shouldn't be.  Actually, if they added an item to the collection and then saved, I would think it's intentional.

Comment: @DR913, that's totally up to you on what you want from a design perspective, but what the other developer wrote to *protect* the collection, just didn't. If yo want the users to be able to add to the collection just setup `public IEnumerable<stuff> things { get; private set; }` and in the `ctor` create a `new` like this `this.things = new List<stuff>();`

Answer (score 0):

Public, internal, and private access modifiers are used to enforce constraints on your application architecture, they aren't intended as a defense against attacks.

I'd recommend you seek out guidance on how to secure web applications. There are plenty of materials available on this topic.